# Eclipse comment line double slash ran to the left

Tags: eclipse

Eclipse comment line can be installed in the statement at the beginning rather than at the left：[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dF6lJ.png)

I want it that way：[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Aqsfv.png)

Comment: Why is this question downvoted! The double slashes stick to the extreme left which breaks the visual flow. How to make the auto single line comment to stay just at the beginning of code and not at col position 0?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ctrl+Shift+F to format the code. Eclipse will slide it over.

Comment: I have tried.that's ok.But do  you have any other way that to press "Ctrl+/" to let "//"  appear near the left of code?